# Operators and lists f#

Tags: list, f#

I have made this code:

```
let rec foo1 z = function
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs when x = z -> x::(foo1 x xs)
  | x::xs -> foo1 z xs
```

but I want a more complex version of this function with a new function which is of type `int -> int -> bool` as first argument. This function will test the integer argument against all the elements of the list, the elements that yields true when the operator is applied should be placed in the return list

Example:

```
let eq x y = x = y
let lt x y = x < y
let gt x y = x > y

foo2 eq 2 [1;2;4;2;5] => [2;2]
foo2 lt 2 [1;2;4;2;5] => [4;5]
foo2 gt 2 [1;2;4;2;5] => [1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/// Pass a function as an argument 
let rec filterByVal fn z = function 
    | [] -> [] 
    | x::xs when fn z x -> x::(filterByVal fn z xs) 
    | _::xs -> filterByVal fn z xs

/// Use anonymous functions
filterByVal (fun z x -> z = x) 2 [1;2;4;2;5] // [2; 2]
filterByVal (fun z x -> z < x) 2 [1;2;4;2;5] // [4; 5]
filterByVal (fun z x -> z > x) 2 [1;2;4;2;5] // [1]

/// Or use symbolic infix functions
filterByVal (=) 2 [1;2;4;2;5]
filterByVal (<) 2 [1;2;4;2;5]
filterByVal (>) 2 [1;2;4;2;5]
```

Comment: That I didn't know, do you know if there is any way to do the same thing but without defining the eq, lt and gt functions?

Comment: Can this only be done with integers or can it be anything else?